# Цикл "for" Java

Tags: java, циклы

Всем привет, как создать на вот этот код цикл?
Я пробовал по такому типу

```
    for (int i = 0;i < 6;i++){
        boolean ai = checkWithRegExp(q1);
        boolean bi = checkWithRegExp1(q2);
    }
```

Но результаты безуспешны. Как в цикле задать, чтобы метод тоже менялся? Ставил
        checkWithRegExp**i**(q**i**) . Выдает ошибку.

```
    boolean a1 = checkWithRegExp(q1);
    boolean b1 = checkWithRegExp1(q2);

    boolean a2 = checkWithRegExp(w1);
    boolean b2 = checkWithRegExp1(w2);

    boolean a3 = checkWithRegExp(e1);
    boolean b3 = checkWithRegExp1(e2);

    boolean a4 = checkWithRegExp(r1);
    boolean b4 = checkWithRegExp1(r2);

    boolean a5 = checkWithRegExp(t1);
    boolean b5 = checkWithRegExp1(t2);
    //
    boolean a6 = checkWithRegExp(q1);
    boolean b6 = checkWithRegExp2(q2);

    boolean a7 = checkWithRegExp(w1);
    boolean b7 = checkWithRegExp2(w2);

    boolean a8 = checkWithRegExp(r1);
    boolean b8 = checkWithRegExp2(r2);

    boolean a9 = checkWithRegExp(e1);
    boolean b9 = checkWithRegExp2(e2);

    boolean a10 = checkWithRegExp(t1);
    boolean b10 = checkWithRegExp2(t2);
    //
    boolean a11 = checkWithRegExp(q1);
    boolean b11 = checkWithRegExp3(q2);

    boolean a12 = checkWithRegExp(w1);
    boolean b12 = checkWithRegExp3(w2);

    boolean a13 = checkWithRegExp(e1);
    boolean b13 = checkWithRegExp3(e2);

    boolean a14 = checkWithRegExp(r1);
    boolean b14 = checkWithRegExp3(r2);

    boolean a15 = checkWithRegExp(t1);
    boolean b15 = checkWithRegExp3(t2);
    //
    boolean a16 = checkWithRegExp(q1);
    boolean b16 = checkWithRegExp3(q2);

    boolean a17 = checkWithRegExp(w1);
    boolean b17 = checkWithRegExp3(w2);

    boolean a18 = checkWithRegExp(e1);
    boolean b18 = checkWithRegExp3(e2);

    boolean a19 = checkWithRegExp(r1);
    boolean b19 = checkWithRegExp3(r2);

    boolean a20 = checkWithRegExp(t1);
    boolean b20 = checkWithRegExp3(t2);
```

Comment: Не заводите миллиард переменных, если с ними нужно делать однотипные действия. Дочитайте учебник до массивов или (лучше) списков.

Comment: Опишите логику ваших методов, как они должны меняться. Одинаковые ли переменные передаете в методы. Как определить какой метод вызывать? То, что написали вы зациклить невозможно, т.к. логика не циклична

Answer (score 1):

Например, можно использовать списки:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Pattern> patternList = Arrays.asList(Pattern.compile("reg1"), Pattern.compile("reg2"), Pattern.compile("reg3"), Pattern.compile("reg4"));
    List<String> dataList = Arrays.asList("str1", "str2", "str3", "str4");

    IntStream.range(0, patternList.size()).forEach(i -> System.out.println(checkWithRegExp(patternList.get(i), dataList.get(i))));
}

private static boolean checkWithRegExp(Pattern pattern, String data) {Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
    return matcher.find();
}
```

Comment: Автор вопроса ещё даже с массивами/списками толком не знаком. А у вас тут сразу и дженерики и Stream API. Подозреваю, что это слишком сложно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin а вдруг знаком и это вопрос касается архитектуры? Кстати, рад буду услышать варианты реализации. На ум приходит лямда.

Comment: «Cтавил  checkWithRegExp**i** (q**i**) . Выдает ошибку.» Похоже, что не знаком. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin может он генерирует сорцы в памяти, компилирует и исполняет?)

Comment: Ребята, я плохо знаком с массивами и списками. Почитаю о них и попытаюсь разобрать код мистера DaysLikeThis. Спасибо всем за ответы.

Comment: @Waluk мой монокль выпал на слове мистер :D

Comment: @DaysLikeThis ахаха